# Are SharedPreferences read-only?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

I know that `SharedPreferences` is an efficient way to store data but is the database used by android to store SharedPreferences read only even if you have root access?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you wanting to access SharedPreferences outside of your application?

Comment: @Weava No, however I don't want the data I'm storing edited via the database even if the user has root access. Sorry if I wasn't clear!

Comment: Ahh, there is nothing you can do if a user has SUDO permission on the device. If a device is rooted, they can dig into your sharedPrefs all they want. If you are storing passwords or other sensitive data, consider doing some sort of cryptographic stuff like SHA or MD5 hashing before adding to prefs.

Comment: @Weava Thank you! Is it possible you could add that as an answer?

Comment: Just did :D, and you're welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing you can do if a user has SUDO permission on the device. If a device is rooted, they can dig into your SharedPreferences all they want.

If you are storing passwords or other sensitive data in your app's local data, consider doing some sort of obfuscation like SHA or MD5 hashing before adding to prefs.